# Uploading app to apps.ionic.io fails silently

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I have just started develoing with ionic following a tutorial. Everythings seems actually quite logical - but now I am trying to upload my simple hello world code without any luck.

On the command line I was able to login on my apps.ionic.io account and I was also able to link my local code with the app that I have created in the browser on apps.ionic.io. My app_id was then written to ionic.config.json.

I am also able to build the app and run it in the android simulator.

But when I execute the following command it just does a build but doesn't seem to upload the generated code:

```
PS D:\IonicTest\ionic-tabs-app> ionic upload --verbose
[DEBUG] Loading global plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy
[DEBUG] Loading local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova
[DEBUG] Loading local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular
Running app-scripts build: --log-level debug

[14:37:02]  build dev started ...
[14:37:02]  clean started ...
[14:37:02]  clean finished in 3 ms
[14:37:02]  copy started ...
[14:37:02]  transpile started ...
[14:37:04]  transpile finished in 2.02 s
[14:37:04]  preprocess started ...
[14:37:04]  deeplinks started ...
[14:37:04]  deeplinks finished in 9 ms
[14:37:04]  preprocess finished in 11 ms
[14:37:04]  webpack started ...
[14:37:04]  copy finished in 2.16 s
[14:37:09]  webpack finished in 5.47 s
[14:37:11]  sass started ...
[14:37:12]  sass finished in 791 ms
[14:37:12]  postprocess started ...
[14:37:12]  postprocess finished in 5 ms
[14:37:12]  lint started ...
[14:37:12]  build dev finished in 9.98 s
PS D:\IonicTest\ionic-tabs-app>
```

When I go to my app on apps.ionic.io I can't see any hint at all that something has been uploaded. Therefore I guess that my upload command actually failed but wasn't brave enough to show me any exception.

Can someone please give me at least an idea where I can start investigating?

Versions: ionic 3.5, cordova 7.0.1, npm 5.3.0

Comment: Did it prompt you to login?

Comment: Yes, when I first tried the upload command it told me first to login.

Comment: try `ionic upload` without --verbose.

Comment: executing the command without --verbose does just not print out the [DEBUG] lines - everything else behaves the same

Comment: make sure correct  `app_id` is used in `ionic.config.json` and `.io-config.json`.

Comment: I don't have any file .io-config.json. I think it's not part of the template which was used by the command `ionic start myApp sidemenu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to ionic CLI version 3.6 the upload is working as expected. I have to say that I have also reinstalled node.js - therefore I can not say what has finally fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Before it failed, the output was the following:

```
> ionic cordova prepare
[WARN] No Cordova platforms listed in config.xml. Nothing to prepare.

       You can save your installed platforms to config.xml with the ionic
       cordova platform save command.
```

Tried reinstalling Node, cordova, ionic, etc. Nothing worked.

At some point I ran `ionic cordova build`.

It asked:

`? What platform would you like to build: ios, android:`

I picked `ios`

It ran for a while. The output now included the lines below which may be relevant:

```
> ionic cordova prepare
> cordova prepare
```

Then I tried `ionic upload` again, and this time it finally worked.